Trying to create a subnet to connect to a network device and I cannot see the IP address in my "route print" list
I'm trying to set up a subnet to connect to a Ubiquiti networking device I need to configure. I can't connect to it. This is on Windows 10.
1 - I've changed my ethernet TCP/IPv4 properties to:
IP: 192.168.1.100
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1 (I've also tried 192.168.1.20)
but
2 - I've used "route print" at the command line (I'm on Windows 10) and there is no 192.168.1.x showing up.
This is the table:
IPv4 Route Table
> > ===========================================================================
> > Active Routes:
> > Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
> >           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.86.1    192.168.86.23     50
> >         127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
> >         127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
> >   127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
> >      192.168.86.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.86.23    306
> >     192.168.86.23  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.23    306
> >    192.168.86.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.23    306
> >         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
> >         224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.86.23    306
> >   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
> >   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.86.23    306
> > ===========================================================================

This seems very odd to me.
I have an ethernet card for my wired connection, and the device is connected to that. I also have a wireless card, which I disable when I try to connect. The device manual says it's default IP address is 192.168.1.20 but I cannot l connect to it and I'm wondering if it's because there is some issue that is reflected in that IPv4 table.
Anyone any ideas?
This is ipcongif /all
 Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Desktop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : lan

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-1B-0D-67-FA-9D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1A-A6-F7-F1-66-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2A-A6-F7-F1-66-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 18-A6-F7-F1-66-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd7f:2d4b:2565:8f50:839a:a262:74e2:aca7(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd7f:2d4b:2565:8f50:e189:dacd:fc3c:aedc(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::725:8942:f1a9:da3d%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.23(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 14 April 2024 14:02:02
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 17 April 2024 09:36:38
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 404268791
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-A8-9F-B9-1C-1B-0D-67-FA-9D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


I'm inferring that this is a windows system. Please show us ipconfig /all.

It is Windows 10, yes. And I've added ipconfig /all

@SubjectiveEffect - The only working adapter per the output of “ipconfig /all” is your wireless adapter. You might have think you set your ipaddress to 192.168.1.100 but the output disagrees with that.

What device and configure how? Resetting it might be a useful step, and most unifi kit I've used tends to 'expect' to be on the network, then adopted. If its not a controller, it might be trying to connect over DHCP

You're skipping a few steps ahead. For IP to work over Ethernet, you need Ethernet itself to be working first – this says it isn't working, i.e. the port has not detected an Ethernet link to any device:
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

It's common for operating systems to not configure IP on disconnected interfaces – they deliberately don't add the subnet routes so that the same subnet could be accessible through another, working interface.

Yeah, that's the thing. If I plug it into the internet it's fine, but when I plug it into the network device it's like this.
However, even plugged into the internet I cannot change the IP address so it shows in ipconfig.

Right, but the point was that you need to make it "not like this" before you can start doing anything IP-related. Your IP configuration is moot if the Ethernet link won't come up first.

are you directly connecting the PC to the Ubiquity device, or are you connecting them both to a switch?

I'm connecting the PC to a POE device that is connected the Ubiquiti device. This is as per the instructions.

Does the device power on, at least? Are you using the PoE device matching the Ubiquiti device, or some other PoE device?

I'm using an Ubiquiti PoE device as recommended by their own tech help. All the power and connection lights seem fine.
